# Implicit class applicable to all Traversable subclasses including Array

Tags: arrays, scala, implicit, scala-2.10, scala-2.11

I've run into a problem trying to create an implicit class applicable to all Traversable subclasses including Array. I tried the following simple example in both Scala 2.11.1 and 2.10.4:

```
implicit class PrintMe[T](a: Traversable[T]) {
  def printme = for (b <- a) print(b)
}
```

As far as I understand this should allow for an implicit conversion to PrintMe so that printme can be called on any Traversable, including List and Array. E.g:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).printme
123
// Great, works as I expected!

scala> Array(1,2,3).printme
<console>:23: error: value printme is not a member of Array[Int]
              Array(1,2,3).printme
// Seems like for an Array it doesn't!

scala> new PrintMe(Array(1,2,3)).printme
123
// Yet explicitly building a PrintMe from an Array works
```

What's going on here? Why does the implicit conversion work for a List and not an Array?

I understand there has been some trickery adapting java Arrays but looking at the picture below from http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html it certainly seems like Array is meant to behave like a subclass of Traversable.

[image: scala.collection.immutable]

Comment: AFAIK only one implicit conversion at a time can be applied. In this case, I am only guessing this now, maybe there is some implicit conversion from java Arrays to Scala Arrays already happening - that's why your conversion is not working.

Comment: Note also that Array is not a subtype, that symbol means that scala has a view on the array class from IndexSeq, which means an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as @goral said: only one implicit conversion can happen at a time.

So you can pass an Array where a Traversable is expected since Array will become a WrappedArray:

```
def printme[T](a: Traversable[T]) { for (b <- a) print(b) }
printme(Vector(1,2,3))
printme(Array(1,2,3))
```

Or you can use your implicit on a manually-wrapped Array:

```
val wa = scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.make(Array(1, 2, 3))
wa.printme
```

But you can't have both at the same time.